# Can't compare expected result for <nobr> tag

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

There is a `nobr` tag with some text:

```
<nobr>+380</nobr>
```

I have described it in `page-object`:

```
elements(:txtCode, :nobr, :xpath => "//td[@id='phone_prefix']/nobr")
```

I need to check its value and I use following expectation:

```
expect(page.txtCode.text).to eql('+380')
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `txtCode' for #<Page:0x3071d30>
```

How do i describe this `nobr` element to bring the `expect()` to work?

Answer (score 0):

You're defining an element collection instead of an element because you're using `elements` instead of `element`. The only method that creates on your page object is `txtCode_elements`. Use `element` instead.

```
element(:txtCode, :nobr, :xpath => "//td[@id='phone_prefix']/nobr")
```

You can read more about element collections from this blog post by Justin Ko: https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/defining-element-collections-using-the-page-objects-gem/